# PersistentVolumeClaim used by multiple pods: one for writing and another for backup

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims

In a Kubernetes cluster on Oracle cloud, I have a pod with an Apache server.

This pod needs a persistent volume so I used a persistentVolumeClaim and the cloud provider is able to automatically create an associated volume (Oracle Block Volume).

The access mode used by the PVC is readWriteOnce and therefore the volume created has the same access mode.

Everything work great.

Now I want to backup this volume using borg backup and borgmatic by starting a new pod regularly with a cronJob.

This backup pod needs to mount the volume in read only.

Question:

- Can I use the previously defined PVC?
- Do I need to create a new PVC with readOnly access mode?

Answer (score 1):

As per documentation:

> ReadWriteOnce:
> the volume can be mounted as read-write by a single node. ReadWriteOnce access mode still can allow multiple pods to access the volume when the pods are running on the same node.

That means if you make a strict rule for deploying  your pods to the same node, you can use the same PVC, here's the [INSTRUCTION](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)